# sp_start_job gets killed by Thread.Sleep in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ssis

Currently I'm stuck in an area I have no (not enough) expertise.
I call a MSSQL job in an on the fly sp with a connectionstring that has "asynchronous processing = true", which is specific for this task.

> ```
> String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbSSIS"].ConnectionString;
> SqlConnection jobConnection;
> SqlCommand jobCommand;
> SqlParameter jobReturnValue;
> SqlParameter jobParameter;                
> int jobResult;
>
> jobConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
> jobCommand = new SqlCommand("msdb.dbo.sp_start_job", jobConnection);
> jobCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
>
> jobReturnValue = new SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
> jobReturnValue.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
>  jobCommand.Parameters.Add(jobReturnValue);
>
> jobParameter = new SqlParameter("@job_name", SqlDbType.VarChar); jobParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
> jobCommand.Parameters.Add(jobParameter); 
> jobParameter.Value = "Jobname";
>
> jobConnection.Open(); jobCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
> jobResult = (Int32)jobCommand.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
> jobConnection.Close();
> ```

The job runs perfectly from code with "msdb.dbo.sp_start_job". But when a add:

> System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

the job stops somewhere in the middle of the job started by the agent. The reason I want the Sleep is because I want to do select calls on an eventtable that is filled by the SSIS. So that I know when it is finished and at what stage it is.

Where is it going wrong with the Sleep?

Comment: Where are you adding this? Are you timing out the connection?

Comment: Are you sure on this? [sp_start_job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186757.aspx) is an asynchronous call and the value of your return value is whether the job *started* or not. The computer that started the job could burn to the ground and the SQL Agent is going to be none-the-wiser as it's doing its thing.